# Comparing two tar.gz

Tags: diff, tar, filesize, gzip

I have two `tar.gz` files I have downloaded from the same URL. One I downloaded using Safari (53.6 MB) and the other one through Chrome (56.9 MB). Extracting them results in two exactly alike folders with 56 MB. Same sizes, same contents. I compared with `diff` and found no difference. I also compared both `tar.gz` files with the following command, but also found no difference:

```
diff <(tar -tvf fileone.tar.gz | sort) <(tar -tvf filetwo.tar.gz | sort)
```

Now, is there any other way I could try to see what the difference between both is?

Comment: If the website provides a md5sum hash you could try to compare it, it won't give you the content but at least you'll know if one of them is not valid

Comment: `53.6*1024*1024/1000/1000` is about 56.3 ... is it possible that one of them is using MiB and calling them MB ?

Comment: @hymie Nope. I have them downloaded locally.